# How to detect fragment change?

Tags: angular, router

I need to identify when an anchor is changed and so call a function

Where I set the fragment:

```
  changeFragment(id) {
    this.router.navigate([], { fragment: id });
  }
```

Any help is welcome, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inject ActivatedRoute service in construtor, Then use fragement method in Activatedroute to listen fragement changes

**Try this:**

```
 this.route.fragment.subscribe( fragment =>{
      console.log(fragment);
 })
```

Comment: Somehow this did not work consistently for me. It would fire once on each fragment change but not again e.g. if my SPA app has 2 pages, one at /home and the other at /report, and i land at /home then on navigating to /report the first time this observable would fire but never again if i navigate away from /report and then come back. I ended up using `router.events.subscribe` as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular.

Comment: Are you using fragment in your routes?

Comment: yes, why do you ask ?