# Angular ActivatedRoute subscription not triggering on route changes

Tags: angular, angular-router

Here is a StackBlitz of the problem I'm facing:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aetvyf?file=src%2Fapp%2F

In AppComponent I'm subscribing to ActivatedRoute.url changes, but they only ever trigger once.

Shouldn't ActivatedRoute.url subscription emit on every route change?

I know I can use Router.events, but there you have to filter by event type and Router events don't have route segments, as ActivatedRoute.snapshot, for instance, does.

I have read all related questions, but none really answer the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular

Comment: you should listen for activated on your navigated component, not on root component.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your code. You must subscribe on you child components i.e. a and b to detect the url changes. Currently you are adding these subscriptions on app.component. Moreover, if you want one app level solution, you have to subscribe to ***Router.events***.

Like this :-

```
constructor(private ar: ActivatedRoute, private r: Router) {
  this.r.events.subscribe((segs) => {
    console.log('Route segments');
    console.log(segs);
  });
}
```

Comment: You can read more about RouterEvent here: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent