# How to render under specific conditions div in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, web-applications

In my angular project I have a side nav-component which I have put in my app-component.html so it will be rendered in every other component (Admin dashboard). But now I have the problem that my sidenav comes in my login screen too which makes sense, because my login html is there as a router-outlet.

I tried to add a variable url and tried with ngIf to render the component only when it is not equal with url=/login but it hided the sidenav in every other compoenent. I do not know how to change it so it will be rendered in every other component except login screen without putting it manually. Maybe someone here can help me out What I want is that <moniesta-client-dashboard... is rendered everywhere except in login component (router-outlet)

this is my app.component.html

```
    <moniesta-client-dashboard-navigation></moniesta-client-dashboard-navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular

Comment: hey I did not quite understand the solution proposed there....sry