# setInterval() does not set data without refreshing the page in angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, setinterval

here is my angular component -

```
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private _subscriptions: Subscription;
  private _users: User[] = [];
  private _clickableUser: boolean = true;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const source = interval(1000);
    const users = this.route.snapshot.data['users'] as IUserInterface[];

    this._subscriptions = source.subscribe(() => this._users = users.map(user => new User(user)))

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._subscriptions.unsubscribe();
  }
```

i get the data, but the interval does not set it without refreshing.

Comment: Did you mean to use setInterval()?

Comment: The ngOnInit has interval(1000) that is what I meant.

Comment: Also can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: @BrianSmith the interval(1000) is from rxjs, so yes its setInterval()

Comment: @BrianSmith i am trying to set data without refreshing the page

Comment: I am not sure of the rest of your app, but it look like you should be using an @Input and pass the 'users' value into this component and not passing via route data. If you can reproduce this in a stackblitz, it will give a better picture.

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnInit()` is only called **once**, when a component is first created. This means that your active route is being read only once, which also means that your `users` array is always the same one.

I'm guessing you are trying to update your component each time the route data gets updated. For that, you need to subscribe to `this.route.data` (notice I didn't include `snapshot`). It will look something like this:

```js
this._subscriptions = this.route.data.subscribe(data => this._users = data['users'].map(user => new User(user));
```

Comment: where can i put the interval?

Comment: @daniel45 you should subscribe to route changes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548895/5819227

Comment: Why do you need the interval in the first place?