# Can we select <a> element when it's routerLink is active in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, queryselector

I want to select `<a>` element by className when its router link is active, but it returns `null`

**navbar.component.html** code:

```
<nav class="profile-navbar">
  <ul>
    <li class="posts-item">
      <a
        [routerLink]="['/app/profile', username, 'posts']"
        routerLinkActive="active-link"
        >Posts</a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="images-item">
      <a
        [routerLink]="['/app/profile', username, 'images']"
        routerLinkActive="active-link"
        >Images</a
      >
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**navbar.component.ts** code:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'profile-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  
  constructor() { 
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const activeLink = document.querySelector('.active-link');
    console.log(activeLink)
  }

}
```

How can I select the element the  element based on routerLinkActive class??

Comment: Why do you need access to that element if I may ask?

Comment: I want to add active link indicator like the style in this codepen https://codepen.io/ohsoren/pen/QNoQwX

Comment: @AsmaaMahmoud, why not use `.active-link::after{......}`?

Comment: @Eliseo, the indicator is not a part of the active-link itself, It's separate element that move under all of them

Comment: @AsmaaMahmoud, you can get using ViewChildren, check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a series of "divs" you can use a template reference variable and ViewChildren. When you has ViewChildren you can find the element with a class or anopther property.

Case of routerLinks the approach is similar, but you can to have in ViewChildren the [routerLinksActive seeing as "ElementRef" and seeing as "RouterLinkActive"

Some like

```
  //links are the "RouterLinkActive"
  @ViewChildren(RouterLinkActive) links:QueryList<RouterLinkActive>
  
  //lisk are the "RouterLinkAvtive" but seeing as ElementRef
  @ViewChildren(RouterLinkActive,{read:ElementRef}) linksElements:QueryList<ElementRef>
  @ViewChild('indicator') indicator:ElementRef
  constructor(private router: Router) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.pipe(
       filter(x=>x instanceof NavigationEnd),
       startWith(null)).subscribe(res=>{

      //we need enclosed in a setTimeout because when the event NavigationEnd
      //happens, Angular are not add the class "active-links"
      // nor link isActive=true
      setTimeout(()=>{

        //first find the "index" in the QueryList
        const index=(this.links.map(
          (x:RouterLinkActive,i:number)=>({isActive:x.isActive,index:i}))          
          .find(x=>x.isActive) || {index:-1}).index
  
        //it's the same index in the ElementRef
        if (index>=0)
        {
          const el=this.linksElements.find((_,i)=>i==index)
          
          //We use the "el" to change the style.top of the indicator
           this.indicator.nativeElement.style.top=
                       el.nativeElement.offsetTop+'px'
        }
        else
        {
          this.indicator.nativeElement.style.top='-100px'
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Where

```
<nav class="profile-navbar">
<ul>
  <li class="posts-item">
    <a
      [routerLink]="['/hello']"
      routerLinkActive="active-link"
      >Posts</a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="images-item">
    <a
      [routerLink]="['/by']"
      routerLinkActive="active-link"
      >Images</a
    >
  </li>
</ul>
<div #indicator class="indicator"></div>
</nav>
```

like is showed in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rmyfn8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this LifeCycleHook try ngDoCheck() instead or listen to the route changes ([How to detect a route change in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular)) and do your selection based on the event or even better just use in your .css file:

```
a.active {
/* your style */
}
```

If you just want to style it, there is usually no need to select it, but in your case with the calculation of translate3d and scaleX I'm not sure...

Comment: It returns the first link that has routerLinkActive attribute with value 'active-link'

Comment: Sorry I missed that, I just updated my answer!

Comment: No problem, I just used querySellectorAll and it works fine, but I was wondering if there is a way to get only the active link.

Comment: And why selecting the element with class name not working?

Comment: Sorry again, I misunderstood your question. The class should be applied but only after ngAfterViewInit. So just use ngAfterViewChecked or just use a css selector.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's it `ngAfterViewChecked()`, but I think it's not good to call the function of positioning the indicator inside `ngAfterViewChecked()`, isn't it?

Comment: @AsmaaMahmoud You should use ngDoCheck() and call your method from there or even better use the router event in a way like Eliseo suggested.